# Prove $ \mathrm{E}\left[\max_{1≤i≤\infty}|S_i|\right]≤2\sqrt{b} $?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X_1, X_2,\ldots$, are independent r.v.s. with mean $0$ such that:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathrm{var}(X_i)=b<\infty $$

How can one prove that:

$$ \mathrm{E}\left[\max_{1≤i≤\infty}|S_i|\right]≤2\sqrt{b} $$

Borel-Cantelli might be useful right?

Comment: Using displaystyle (two dollar signs) in titles is discouraged, as they take up too much space.  I have fixed it.

Comment: what is $S_i$ here?

Comment: @Norbert $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ is the usual notation.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** [Use Kolmogorov's maximal inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_inequality): this gives that for each $n$, 
$$\mathbb P\left\{\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}|S_j|\geqslant t\right\}\leqslant \min\left\{\frac{b}{t^2},1\right\}.$$
Then we use the relationship $\mathbb E(Y)=\int_0^\infty\mathbb P\{Y\geqslant t\}\mathrm dt$ for any non-negative $Y$. We conclude by a monotone convergence argument.